# Excitation of an electron

Tags: atomic-physics, photoelectric-effect

What effect does a light ray cause on an electron to make it excited. How a electron absorb energy?

Comment: My question is how a electron get excited from a proton or light ray

Answer (score 3):

It is not an electron, but the atom it is associated with that absorbs energy.  A free electron is incapable of absorbing a photon due to the requirements of energy and momentum conservation. In an atom, however, an electron can absorb a photon and jump from one bound state to another (or leave the atom completely).

Comment: But how a electron can absorb energy